# Should I keep a SerialPort connection open?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, serial-communication

I am working with serial communication and I'm wondering whether I should keep the SerialPort open or not?

I'm creating a queue of commands and only one will be running at a time. Should I create a SerialPort and open/close it in each command, or should I have another class which holds the port open and is called from the commands? Or does it really matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using a COM port - Close after each use, or leave always open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777516/using-a-com-port-close-after-each-use-or-leave-always-open)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep it open.  No point to have the overhead of opening and closing it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to C. Ross's answer, keeping it open will prevent anything else from opening the SerialPort and blocking you later.  I would suggest keeping it open.