# using a COM port - Close after each use, or leave always open?

Tags: c#, serial-port

Till now I opened when I needed to send data, and closed right away.
I get random "Access to Port" errors (although I always close the port after I use it),
so I was thinking maybe to leave it always open.

What is the right approach of use, assuming that every minute or two I need to send data in some COM ports?

Thanks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling SerialPort.Close() frequently is a mistake.  Having another app steal the port away from you isn't exactly very desirable.  But more problematic, and the problem you are having, is that Close() doesn't wait for a worker thread that is started by SerialPort to exit.  That worker thread raises the DataReceived, PinChanged and ErrorReceived events.  It takes "a while" for it to exit, could be between milliseconds and seconds.  Calling Open() again will fail until that's done.

It's a flaw in the class, but induced by the common usage for serial ports.  Apps don't normally close them until the app terminates.  Including never, avoiding a common deadlock scenario.  Do note that the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.close.aspx) for Close warns about this:

> The best practice for any application is to wait for some amount of time after calling the Close method before attempting to call the Open method, as the port may not be closed instantly.

Comment: Thank you. I aware of this delay but in the usage of my application there is at least 30 seconds between each Close and Open so I didn't think that it might the reason for the random locks.
I I will leave the ports open.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about the opening/closing and other apps stealing the COM port away, you could use the approach used by Microsoft for the GPS intermediate driver in windows embedded, i.e. to write an aggregator, one which opens the port, keeps it open, then provides connection points for other apps to connect to.

How you create the connections is up to you: you can get right down deep in the hardware and write a virtual com port driver that's shareable, or you can do what I did and write a simple win32 socket service that allows client programs to connect via regular windows socket connections.

Maybe not a straight forward answer, but food for thought.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't need/want other apps to use the COM ports while I'm using it, so I will leave it always open.

Comment: no sweat, my answer was posted as a "Further food for thought" approach to the question anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is very little harm in leaving a serial port open, so yes, keep it open. It saves you the overhead of open/closing it.

Comment: Thank you. I will leave it open.