# RS232 Keep connection or open, close per request

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port, hardware-interface

I am developing an application using C# to send command to RS232 serial port.

Currently, when program start the application will permanently connect to RS232 port and application close port only when it is shut-downed.

My question: it is good to open/close RS232 each time we send command or we keep connection to RS232 permanently when application start?

Thanks.

Comment: No, that would be a pretty bad idea.  It takes a while after the Close() or Dispose() call before you can open the port again, the worker thread that generates the events has to terminate.  How long that takes is unpredictable.  There is no benefit either to another process stealing the port away from you, making the Open() call fail.  Unless that is an explicit requirement.

Comment: Noted, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Strictly speaking, RS232 ports aren't opened or closed.  At most the UART is configured and perhaps something is done with the modem status lines.  The thing which you are opening or closing is the operating system *driver* instance, not the port itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using a COM port - Close after each use, or leave always open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777516/using-a-com-port-close-after-each-use-or-leave-always-open)